# How to find out if an email is already registered with Firebase Simple Login?

Tags: html, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I am using firebase (with Angularfire) for an html5 phone app. The user inputs only their email in the start screen, and then, depending on whether that email is already registered or not, the user is redirected to the login or registration page, respectively. For step1, how can we query the firebase simple login to determine if the email is registered or not?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Update 7/19/2018**

The previous mention method is deprecated. Now [fetchSignInMethodsForEmail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail) is used.

**Update 6/26/2016**

A lot has changed since this was originally posted, Firebase Authentication is no longer called Firebase Simple Login.

Additionally, it looks like a new method is available `fetchProvidersForEmail` which might provide a solution to this problem.

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword):

> fetchProvidersForEmail(email) returns firebase.Promise containing non-null Array of string
>
> Gets the list of provider IDs that can be used to sign in for the given email address. Useful for an "identifier-first" sign-in flow.

I have not tested this but I'd imagine if you call that method and receive an array of providers then the e-mail must already be registered with one or more authentication providers.

**Old Answer**

I don't believe you can query the Firebase Simple Login directly for that information without either trying to actually login the user or register them.

What you'd need to do is store a list of registered e-mails during your registration process and query that list instead. Then you can query that path and if it comes back with data, it exists, otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: +1 and thanks, this approach of a separate index seems to the only viable one in the absence of a way to query firebase simple login. I will give the question a bit more time for the firebase folks to confirm this approach before marking your response as the answer.

Comment: It's the best option but not the only option. You could, for example, just try to create the user and see if it succeeds; if it fails, it will tell you it already exists in the error.

Comment: @Kato - there are scenarios where that gets convoluted. For example, if the user starts the sign-up process but decides not to complete it today. Now you've created that account with, presumably, some known password. That account is now vulnerable to take-over by someone else, or if a random password is used, the user themselves may not be able to register the next day. There are ways to deal with all of the above - but you'd just be adding a lot of complexity where it doesn't belong.

Comment: @Jarnal - one other thing to consider is how you're going to control security around that list of e-mails. I don't know the details of your app but it'd be a risk to have a publicly readable list of your users' e-mails available. You should hide this list behind privileged code running on a server with a custom Firebase auth token, or figure out some way to set the Firebase rules so that read permissions are denied, opting instead for a combination of validate/write rules to detect if an address exists.

Comment: @MikePugh all great points. Re listing user emails: The read permissions are simplest . If the parent path is read: false, and only the child ids are readable, then there is no way to get a list of emails, but a single, known email can still be checked for existence.

Comment: @Kato ah, that is a simple solution! Thanks

Comment: Does anybody have a decent solution for this problem after 2 years?

Comment: @MikePugh, it’s impossible, because you can’t store emails as keys (if you’re checking for emails as login). It is only solution if you’re using username as login.

Comment: @Vasily - you could md5 hash the e-mails and compare that way

Comment: Hey all, I have write down the solution in answer and it is working for me. In a case if still any help is required.

Comment: @MuhammadAdil this entire thread is a bit old. It appears that the newest Firebase API includes a method "fetchProvidersForEmail" which could possibly be used to handle the task of determining if an account exists already.

Comment: @MikePugh thanks man, It is really helpful .. Actually I was trying this solution but I haven't think on this that it is an asynchtask and it has completion listener.

Comment: Unfortunately fetchProvidersForEmail does not returns Facebook provider with a matching email address. I would hope it would catch that case instead of letting two accounts under the same email (even if the fb id is used instead, from the user's perspective its still duplicating his identity)

Comment: @nobre - did you contact Firebase support with that?

Comment: @MikePugh I just contacted them about it

Comment: @MikePugh I've been trying to get this to work for literally two days. No matter what I do , I can't seem to get the `fetchProvidersForEmail` method to work. Can you post a basic outline of how I can accomplish this?

Comment: @Ethan there are a lot of reasons why it may not work - potentially related to how your app is setup in your Firebase console (ie, which providers you have configured, ensuring you have your local dev server setup properly). I'd recommend you reach out to Firebase support with more specifics of what exactly isn't working, they should be able to get you on track.

Comment: @MikePugh I found an interposing work-around to this actually. I try to sign the user in with their proposed email address and an empty password and, based on the response I get from `Firebase`, can determine whether or not the email is available. See my post about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676779/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-is-already-in-use-firebase)

Comment: Another year has passed. I'm interested in acheiving the same as OP. Can any of the commenters confirm that `fetchProvidersForEmail` is a solution for EmailAuthProvider? If the email that you pass to it has a registered email auth user, it will be returned in the ProviderQueryResult?

Answer (score 17):

Well Following #Kato's and #MikePugh's commented suggestions I am gonna write this solution and it worked for me.

**Solutio#1 (highly recommended)**

```
 mAuth.fetchProvidersForEmail("emailaddress@gmail.com").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ProviderQueryResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ProviderQueryResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
          ///////// getProviders().size() will return size 1. if email ID is available. 
                task.getResult().getProviders().size();
            }
        }
    });
```

**Solution#2**

Create a dummy **FirebaseUser** object.

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = null;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private void isEmailAlreadyUsed() {
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

///// here I am gonna create dummy user at **Firebase** with the Entered email Id (Email to check against) 

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mEmailView.getText().toString(), "dummypass")
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "createUser:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());


                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        /////user do not exit so good to initialize firebase user.              
                    firebaseUser = task.getResult().getUser();
                    } else {
                        if(task.getException().getMessage().equals("The email address is already in use by another account.")) {
                          Log.d(TAG, "This email ID already used by someone else");     
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Later on when user enter password and press **SIGNUP** button then you can just update password of the user which was set as **dummypass**.

```
   boolean isSignUpMade = false;
    if (firebaseUser != null)
        firebaseUser.updatePassword(password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        signUpCallProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            isSignUpMade = true;
                            Log.d(TAG, "User password updated.");
                        } else {
                            isSignUpMade = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "User password not updated.");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

You can see I have used **isSingUpMade** variable just to insure that user presses **SINGUP** button.

If user wants to leave without signing up than that dummy user must be deleted from **FIREBASE** server.

so here is the logic.

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!isSignUpMade) {
        if (firebaseUser != null)
            firebaseUser.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "User account deleted.");
                    }
                }
            });
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A little easier example to understand how to catch if the user already exists when signing up with email / password

1. Catch the error
2. If "auth/email-already-in-use" exist
3. Call another function that contains `.signInWithEmailAndPassword()`

**Example**

```
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

    .catch(error => {
      // Handle Errors here.
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;

      // Catch this errorCode to know if user exists
      if (errorCode === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
        // Call function X to sign user in instead
        signInMail(email, password);
        return;
      } 

      // Weak password?
      else if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
        console.log('The password is too weak.');
      } 

     else {
        console.log(errorMessage);
      }
      console.log(error);
    })
```

**Important part that you want to use in your own code would be this**

```
.catch(error => {
      // Handle Errors here.
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      if (errorCode === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
        console.log('This email is already in use');
        // Your action
        return;
      }
    })
```

Comment: from where I will know the password?

Comment: In some flows you wouldnt want to create an account first. But this solution is valid if there is no problem of creating an account in firebase if the user does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

**Service**

```js
import {
    AbstractControl,
    AsyncValidatorFn,
} from '@angular/forms';

import { Observable, of, timer, from } from "rxjs";
import { map, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";

import { Auth, fetchSignInMethodsForEmail } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class EmailValidators {

    constructor(
        private auth: Auth,
    ) {
    }

    public searchEmailAddress(emailAddress: string): Observable<Array<string>> {
        console.log(`searchUser >> emailAddress = ${emailAddress}`);

        if (emailAddress) {
            // debounce
            return timer(1000)  // wait 1 second before searching to reduce API requests
                .pipe(
                    switchMap(() => {
                        return from(fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(this.auth, emailAddress));
                    })
                );
        } else {
            return of([]);
        }
    }

    public emailValidator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<any> => {
            return this.searchEmailAddress(control.value)
                .pipe(
                    map((res: Array<string>) => {
                        console.log(res);

                        // if sign-in methods exist for the email address, it is used
                        if (res.length) {
                            // return error
                            return { emailExists: true };
                        } else {
                            return null;
                        }
                    })
                );
        };
    }
}
```

**Component TypeScript**

```js
import {
    FormGroup,
    FormBuilder,
    Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';

import { EmailValidators } from "../server.service";

export class NewAccountComponent {
    public NewAccountForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(
        private emailValidators: EmailValidators,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    ) {
        this.NewAccountForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            emailAddress: [
                "",
                Validators.compose(
                    [Validators.required, Validators.email],
                ),
                this.emailValidators.emailValidator() // custom async validator
            ],
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            password: "",
            confirmPassword: "",
            agreePrivacyPolicy: false,
        });
    }
}
```

**Component HTML**

```html
<form [formGroup]="NewAccountForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(NewAccountForm)">
  <!-- emailAddress -->
  <div class="row mt-1 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col">
      <kendo-floatinglabel text="Email Address" class="w-75">
        <input kendoTextBox #emailChild type="email" formControlName="emailAddress" autocomplete="email" [email]="true"
          required />
      </kendo-floatinglabel>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Check if email address exists -->
  <div class="row mt-2 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col">
      <div *ngIf="NewAccountForm.get('emailAddress')!.pending" class="cross-validation-error-message alert alert-info">
        Searching...
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="NewAccountForm.get('emailAddress')!.errors?.emailExists"
        class="cross-validation-error-message alert alert-danger">
        Email address has already been used.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- other fields and submit ... -->
</form>
```

Answer (score -4):

You can add following codes before register()_method in your registerActivity.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if(email.equals(user.getEmail().trim())) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Email is taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Hi, getCurrentUser() would return the currently signed in user. If the user is just registering he won't be signed in and getCurrentUser() would return an object without an email.